# pip3 is unable to create virtual environment on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Windows 10 because ensurepip is not available

Tags: python3, 20.04, pip

I was working with virtual environments with **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** but I uninstalled it and installed **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** on windows 10, but now when I create `venv` then error is

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.
```

when I install `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` it say installed but still struggling badly

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-venv is already the newest version (3.8.2-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to add the [deadsnake-ppa](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and install

```
sudo apt install python3.8-venv
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on this while having the same problem.

The answer by @alexandre-b solved it for me. Wanted to post here because of this questions search ranking. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56228901

basically:

```
python3.* -m venv myvenv
```

where `*` is your specific python version.

You can check your python version with

```
python3 --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

1. `virtualenv my1` instead of `python3 -m venv my1`.
2. `cd my1`
3. `source bin/activate`